# Fade image in ms powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I add a fading effect to a picture in MS Power Point?
So that, beginning my picture has low opacity, and after I click on page, its opacity comes to 100% with fading. Or start from bottom to top, or left to right etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Powerpoint 2007...

Select the item, then got to Animation ->Custom Animation ->Add Effect ->Emphasis ->More Effects... ->Transparency